# Format string as currency

Tags: c#

I have `string` variable that contain price. For example, `10000`.  I want  use a space for thousand separator.
e.g. display `10000` as `10 000`, `150000` as `150 000`
How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
    NumberFormatInfo info = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
    info.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";

    Console.WriteLine(12345.ToString("n", info )); // 12 345.00
```

Comment: Parse strin to int or decimal, to use common solution for working with numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Convert manually using linq:

```
var n = "10000000";
var s = n
    .Select((c, i) => c + ((n.Length - i - 1) % 3 == 0 ? " " : ""))
    .Aggregate((s2, s3) => s2 + s3);
```